# How to retain the original workbook during SaveAs

Tags: vba, macros, save

I am trying to retain the original workbook opened and close all other saved(saved with different names) files without reopening. I am doing the SaveAs through a button click. Any suggestions on this?

```
sub save()
     Application.DisplayAlerts= False 
     FileName1 = Range("D4")
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="C:\Users\felonj\Desktop\list\" & FileName1 & "-" & "Audit checklist" & ".xlsm"
     MsgBox "File Saved successfully!", , "Save"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to use your code, try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub save()

    Dim obj_wb As Object

    Set obj_wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "Audit checklist" & ".xlsm"
    MsgBox "File Saved successfully!", , "Save"
    Debug.Print obj_wb.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set obj_wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

obj_wb is the old file, accessible through this variable. Probably it is a good idea to use "ThisWorkbook" in stead of "ActiveWorkbook". Or to refer it always as a variable and not to use any of those at all.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green check next to it.